# INNER JOIN shows only first row in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in my database:

scu_banks:

```
---------------------------------
|   id    |   type   |   name   |
|-------------------------------|  
|    1    |    1     |   One    |
|    2    |    1     |   Two    |
|    3    |    2     |  Three   |
|    4    |    3     |   Four   |
---------------------------------
```

scu_statement:

```
---------------------------------
|   id    |   code   |   mutation   |
|-----------------------------------|  
|    1    |    1     |     100      |
|    2    |    1     |     200      |
|    3    |    2     |     500      |
|    4    |    1     |     500      |
-------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is I want to select all the rows in table `scu_banks` and show the total sum of mutations. The data should be represented like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| scu_banks.type | scu_banks.name |   total   | scu_banks.id |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       1        |      One       | € 800.00  |      1       |
|       1        |      Two       | € 500.00  |      2       |
|       2        |     Three      | €   0.00  |      3       |
|       3        |      Four      | €   0.00  |      4       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run my sql statement I get the following data:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| scu_banks.type | scu_banks.name |    total   | scu_banks.id |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       1        |      One       | € 1300.00  |      1       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The data I get in this case is not correct. € 1300.00 it the total of all the mutations in table `scu_statement`. The statement also dont shows the other rows in the database.

Does someone know what is wrong with my sql statement?

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT      scu_banks.type,
            scu_banks.name, 
            CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(IFNULL(SUM(scu_statement.mutations), 0),2)) AS total, 
            scu_banks.id
FROM        scu_banks
INNER JOIN  scu_statement
ON          scu_banks.id = scu_statement.code
```

Comment: explain the logic to calculate total. And what are those mutations ?? and xmen thing?

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the aggregation in a subquery and left join it to the banks.

```
SELECT b.type "scu_banks.type",
       b.name "scu_banks.name",
       concat('€ ', format(coalesce(x.mutation, 0), 2)) "total",
       b.id "scu_banks.id"
       FROM scu_banks b
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.code,
                              sum(s.mutation) mutation
                              FROM scu_statement s
                              GROUP BY s.code) x
                      ON x.code = b.id;
```