# LEFT JOIN returns a wrong total

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my database:

scu_banks

```
----------------------------
|  id  |   name   |  type  |
|  1   |   One    |   1    |
|  2   |   Two    |   2    |
|  3   |  Three   |   1    |
|  4   |  Four    |   1    |
----------------------------
```

scu_bankstatement

```
--------------------------------------
|  type  | code | mutations | status |
|   1    |  1   |    100    |    1   |
|   1    |  1   |    100    |    0   |
|   1    |  1   |    -50    |    1   |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to show the following data:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  type  |   name   | status1 | status2 | total | id |
|   1    |   One    |    1    |    2    |  150  | 1  |
|   2    |   Two    |    0    |    0    |   0   | 2  |
|   1    |  Three   |    0    |    0    |   0   | 3  |
|   1    |   Four   |    0    |    0    |   0   | 4  |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Status1 should represent the total of the rows where the status = 0 and Status2 should represent the total of the rows where the status = 1.

I am using the following statement:

```
SELECT b.type 'scu_banks.type', b.name 'scu_banks.name', count(l.status) 'status1', count(s.status) 'status2', concat('€ ', format(coalesce(x.mutations, 0), 2)) 'total', b.id 'scu_banks.id' 

FROM scu_banks b 

LEFT JOIN scu_bankstatement l 
ON l.code = b.id AND l.status = 0 

LEFT JOIN scu_bankstatement s 
ON s.code = b.id AND s.status = 1 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.code, sum(s.mutations) mutations 
           FROM scu_bankstatement s 
           GROUP BY s.code) x ON x.code = b.id 
           GROUP BY b.id, b.name, b.type
```

When I execute the statement I get total "2" in the columns 'status1' and 'status2':

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  type  |   name   | status1 | status2 | total | id |
|   1    |   One    |    2    |    2    |  150  | 1  |
|   2    |   Two    |    0    |    0    |   0   | 2  |
|   1    |  Three   |    0    |    0    |   0   | 3  |
|   1    |   Four   |    0    |    0    |   0   | 4  |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Does someone know why I am getting a incorrect response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN shows only first row in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918688/inner-join-shows-only-first-row-in-table)

Comment: I don't follow the logic of your query.  Why do `Three` and `Four` having zeroes in both status columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count with LEFT JOIN shows only one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938022/count-with-left-join-shows-only-one-row)

Comment: @Simonare, you know the possible duplicates you mentioned where both asked by the same person, right? The same person asking this question.

Comment: I am using the same datatables. This does not make my question a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the scu_bankstatement twice, so you will get double number of rows for the matching rows. You do not need to join the table twice.

Also note that the x.mutations should be included into the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
    b.type 'scu_banks.type', 
    b.name 'scu_banks.name', 
    sum(if(l.status=0, 1, 0)) 'status1', 
    sum(if(l.status=1, 1, 0)) 'status2', 
    concat('€ ', format(coalesce(x.mutations, 0), 2)) 'total', 
    b.id 'scu_banks.id' 
FROM scu_banks b 

LEFT JOIN scu_bankstatement l 
ON l.code = b.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.code, sum(s.mutations) mutations 
           FROM scu_bankstatement s 
           GROUP BY s.code) x ON x.code = b.id 
GROUP BY b.id, b.name, b.type, x.mutations
```